# DateTimeFormat Conversion issues in Non-English locale

Tags: java, localization, datetime-format

I have a below code, which does the date conversion in my Java application.

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;    

DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
    String val = df.format("Sat Apr 01 2017 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    ");
    println( "val" );
```

If application is started in English locale
console has: "01-Apr-2017 01:30"

but if it is a German or French locale
console has: "01-Apr.-2017 01:30"

Anyone any idea why the additional dot(.) is coming.

Comment: Dot is probably a locale-specific thing related to month format in whatever locale is a "Non-English" for you. To get rid of it, use `DateTimeFormat` with hard-bound locale (to EN_US, for example). I cannot tell you more because I don't know what is that `DateTimeFormat` class you're using.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I got this behavior for German(de_DE) and French(fr_FR) and I am using com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat class

Comment: The dot signifies an abbreviation. Since ‘Apr’ is an abbreviation for ‘April’, the dot is appropriate in many languages.

Comment: Man that API has a lot of moving parts. Try `DateTimeFormat.getFormat(<pattern>, new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo())`, looks like it might do the trick.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov That API is indeed an awful mess. That is why it has been supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid the legacy date-time classes.

Answer (score 0):

## Cultural Norms of Locale

A `Locale` specifies two things:

- Human language to use in translation of name of month and name of day and such.
- Cultural norms used in matters of abbreviation, punctuation, and order of items in presentation.

You specified a `Locale` where the cultural norm is to append a FULL STOP to an abbreviated Month name.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` and `.ofLocalized`.